# Next.js 13 Force HTTPS

Tags: reactjs, heroku, next.js

I'm working with Next.js 13 and Heroku. I've seen shockingly few up to date guides on how to handle SSL with Next & Heroku. My current set up is taken from [this blog post](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-enforce-https-on-heroku-deployed-apps-i-e-react-6dd30f9fc4c) and shown below. This works, but Google does not like the redirect so it **hurts** SEO. What is the current best practice to ensure HTTPS with Next.js 13 & Heroku?

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useLocation} from "react-router";

const UseRedirectToHttps = () => {
    let location = useLocation()
    useEffect(() => {
        
        if (window.location.protocol!=="https:") {
            window.location.replace("https://your-website-url.com"+location.pathname);
        }
    })
};

export default UseRedirectToHttps;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the best way to solve this is to not use Heroku. Deploying the website to Vercel (the company that maintains Next.js) solves this issue and makes SSL far easier.